# xslt concat text string before and after <newline/>

Tags: jquery, xslt

I have the below xml:

```
    <node1>
    some text here
    <newline/>
    and some text here.
    </node1>
```

the xml is 3rd party generated, hence can't modify it. I simply want to copy the text and ignore the `<newline/>`. Currently, I am getting the below output:

```
    some text here<newline/>and some text here
```

While I want this output, replacing the newline tag with a whitespace:

```
    some text here and some text here
```

Please help.
Thanks!

Comment: can you show the code you are using to do this?

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I am using xslt 1.0 with the below code:
    <xsl:template match="node1">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:template>

Comment: You need to show the actual XSLT code (edit your post, don't add it in a comment)... `normalize-space()` should work if applied in the right context.

Comment: Actually, it has to be transformed to an intermediate xml, which is later translated to html.

Comment: @Jim: there was a mistake in the output above, the <newline/> is getting written to the processed xml. I just want to prevent this node from getting written in to the next xml.

Comment: correction: I just want to prevent this tag <newline/> from getting written in to the next xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this XSLT 1.0;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
   <xsl:template match="node1">
      <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space()" />
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will give you,

```
some text here and some text here.
```

Comment: i tried it here - http://xslttest.appspot.com/ got result 'some text here and some text here.'